# Find id of maximum value and average pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, pyspark

How do I find the id of maximum value of another column and average value using pyspark dataframe?

`df`:

```
+-------------+-------+----------+---------+----------+--------+------+------------------+
|ChargingEvent|   CPID| StartDate|StartTime|   EndDate| EndTime|Energy|    PluginDuration|
+-------------+-------+----------+---------+----------+--------+------+------------------+
|     16673806|AN11719|2017-12-31| 14:46:00|2017-12-31|18:00:00|   2.4|3.2333333333333334|
|     16670986|AN01706|2017-12-31| 11:25:00|2017-12-31|13:14:00|   6.1|1.8166666666666667|
|      3174961|AN18584|2017-12-31| 11:26:11|2018-01-01|12:54:11|    24|25.466666666666665|
```

Current code:

```
df.agg({'PluginDuration': 'max'}).show()
df.agg({'PluginDuration': 'avg'}).show()
```

Then rename the all of the columns to as like the expected outcome below:

```
+-------------------+-------------------+------------------+
|id                 |max_value          |avg_value
+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
| QWER              |96.26              |12.35              |
```

`id` rename from `CPID`. And `max_value` & `avg_value` needs to round up to 2 decimal places.

Comment: Do you need to use dataframe methods or is an SQL approach ok?

Comment: Dataframe method, preferrably. But iI'm open @StuartMills

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have basically adapted an SQL approach to fit into the dataframe methods, which works and answers the question.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

# get the max and average values from the column
mx = df.agg({'PluginDuration':'max'}).collect()[0][0]
av = df.agg({'PluginDuration':'avg'}).collect()[0][0]

# add max and avg olumns, then select cols with rename
# and then sort by value and limit to top
df\
  .withColumn('max_value', F.lit(round(mx,2)))\
  .withColumn('avg_value', F.lit(round(av,2)))\
  .sort('PluginDuration', ascending = False)\
  .selectExpr('CPID as id', 'max_value', 'avg_value')\
  .limit(1)\
  .show()
```

Comment: what is `F.lit` for?

Comment: The second argument in `.withColumn` needs to be a column, but the max value is a single value, `lit` just converts a value to a column so that the dataframe gets a whole column. [lit](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.lit.html) and [withColumn](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.withColumn.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
def extract(self):
    df = self.spark_session.read.csv(self.input_path,header=True)

    return df

def transform(self, df):

    from pyspark.sql.functions import sum, avg, max
    from pyspark.sql.functions import col

    df1=df.withColumn('PluginDuration',
                      col('PluginDuration').cast('double'))

    df2=df1.groupBy("CPID") \
        .agg(max("PluginDuration").alias("max_duration"),avg("PluginDuration").alias("avg_duration"))

  

    #df2.show(truncate=False)

    df3 = df2.select(col("CPID").alias("chargepoint_id"),
                    func.round(df2["max_duration"], 2).alias("max_duration"),
                    func.round(df2["avg_duration"], 2).alias("avg_duration"))

    #df3.show(truncate=False)

    return df3

def load(self, df):
    df.write.parquet(self.output_path)
```

output looks like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMx5u.png)